# how does cpu reaches 100%

Tags: multithreading, cpu, multicore

Please excuse me for this trivial question, But I am bit confused here.

As per my understanding, a cpu/core executes one instruction at a time. If that is the case then why does it sometimes reaches to 100%. Ideally if there are more instructions to executes, they must be added to some queue and whenever cpu gets time, it should pick these instructions one by one and executes them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not really sure what this question means, executing one at a time (which is a huge simplification and not at all what actually happens) doesn't preclude reaching "100%" (which doesn't even mean much)

Comment: A modern core executes far more than one instruction at a time, Haswell can do 7.  A core only ever *doesn't* run at 100% when it is halted by the operating system.  Which happens when it can't find any work to do for the core, very common.  The odds that this comment is helpful ought to be 0%.

Comment: If CPUs worked as you describe, any time that the CPU were to do **anything**, you would have 100% CPU usage.

Comment: The main reason is that while a Cpu *might* be executing an instruction (or more) at each clock cycle, it is often *waiting* for some piece of data to be fetched from memory. Hence while it is waiting, it is not computing at its maximum capacity. And conversely, when it has everything it needs, it maxes out its computation throughput.